# jQuery, unable to check a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I simply have a checkbox that I want to control the visibility of a dropdown below it by checkbox's status.

```
<div class="coral-Form-fieldwrapper">
    <label class="coral-Checkbox">
        <input class="coral-Checkbox-input" id="select-all-namespaces" data-init="checkbox" checked data-type="checkbox" data-config-id="selectAll">
            <span class="coral-Checkbox-checkmark"></span>
            <span class="coral-Checkbox-description">Select All</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="coral-Form-fieldwrapper">
    <span class="coral-Select some-selection-class" data-init="select" data-config-id="tagNamespaces" name="tagNamespaces">
        <button type="button" class="coral-Select-button coral-MinimalButton">
            <span class="coral-Select-button-text">{{i18n "Select something"}}</span>
        </button>
        <select class="coral-Select-select" multiple="true">
            {{#each configOptions}}
                <option value="{{encodeForHTMLAttr this.id}}">{{this.label}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript that controls it:

```
var $an = $("#select-all-namespaces");
var $tn = $(".some-selection-class")
if($an.data("default")) { // I broke point into this statement, made sure 'checked' prop set to true 
    $an.prop("checked", true);
    $tn.hide();
} else {
    $an.prop("checked", false);
    $tn.show();
}
$an.on("click", function() {
    if($an.is(":checked")) {
        $tn.hide();
    } else {
        $tn.show();
    } 
});
```

However, the checkbox loads by default as 'unchecked', after clicking it, the dropdown shows up, but my issue is the checkbox can never be checked, so the dropdown won't disappear. I wonder what's preventing me from setting 'checked' status.

Sigh...Fiddle seems to work well :(

http://jsfiddle.net/9cn2cLrx/

Comment: have you tried .attr('checked', true) instead of prop?

Comment: @Eric yea, they both work the same.

Comment: make a fiddle please

Comment: If the jsfiddle works, the problem/error must be elsewhere. Optimizing your code including the rest like [**so**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/9cn2cLrx/1/) might help you catch the problem if it's not your server acting up on you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle that should be working. Two things that I did were add `type="checkbox"` and add `data-default="true"` to the `#select-all-namespaces` element. It wasn't entirely clear what behavior you are going for but you can change the data-default value to change if the checkbox is checked or not by default.

https://jsfiddle.net/vryjpjhp/

Comment: you should put these requests on the comments, not the answers.

Comment: @mmilleruva, missing type="checkbox" was my problem, somewhere else in my code needs data-type="checkbox" too. Thanks for providing an idea.